# How do the changes to install() in CMake 3.21 affect its typical use?

Tags: installation, cmake, build, idioms

Installation with CMake has always (well, so far) been a tricky process, involving multiple command invocations and notions such as version files, export sets and so on.

Now, it's true that there may have been some more changes to `install()` and related commands between 2017 and now, but - in [CMake 3.21's release notes](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.21.html) I see 4 changes to the `install()` command and at least one change to `IMPORTED_TARGETS`. Specifically, some of this regards dependency management.

So, how should we change our `CMakeLists.txt` files, our project configuration files, and the directions to developers wishing to depend on our CMake projects, to avail ourselves of these new capabilities?

Comment: This question invites to write a (video-)blog about CMake install-related features introduced in 3.21 version. But this opposes to the Stack Overflow intention, which expects questions to be about a **specific problem** one wants to solve.

Comment: The part of the video you link to tells about installing a library linked with some IMPORTED library, but when one does **not** want to **install** that IMPORTED library **along** with the project. Among new `install` features I see no one which could help in that installation. E.g. `install(IMPORTED_TARGETS)` installs an IMPORTED library along with the project.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Removed the link.

Comment: @KamilCuk: Yes, edited.